Separate Test Set for Cross-Validation for Small Sample (n=140)
I’m working on a survival analysis model with a small internal dataset (n=140). An outside researcher suggests splitting the dataset into train/val and setting aside a separate test set (e.g., ~10%, or 14 samples) for evaluation. However, I’m concerned that further splitting the already small dataset might compromise the reliability of the results.
Would it be more appropriate to perform cross-validation on the entire dataset without setting aside a separate test set, or is splitting it still necessary?

Estimation using 90% of the data would be about 95% as efficient as using all of it  (standard errors would be about 5.4% larger).

See this post.

Although a model developed on 126 cases might not be much different from one developed on all 140, the remaining 14 cases will be too few to test the model adequately (as you sense). This is even more of a problem with survival data: the number of events, not the total number of cases, provides power.
What your colleague proposed is equivalent to 1/10 of a single round of cross validation. Unless you have tens of thousands of cases, Frank Harrell recommends more thorough internal validation with bootstrapping or repeated cross validation (100 repeats with different random data splits). Those processes document the quality of the model-building process.

I discuss here why split sample validation doesn’t work well until $n > 20,000$.
